# SQL: Finding the average number of days between runs for each runners

Tags: mysql, sql

So if we have the following table given:

```
runner  ran
Carol   2011-02-01
Alice   2011-02-01
Bob     2011-02-01
Carol   2011-02-02
Bob     2011-02-02
Bob     2011-02-03
Bob     2011-02-04
Carol   2011-02-07
Alice   2011-02-08
```

How can I write a query (without any subquery) to find the average number of days each runner has to wait between runs (i.e, Carol waited 1 day, then 5, so average is 3; Bob runs everyday; Alice waited 7 days)?

I was thinking about a join on the table itself, then finding the max and min for each runner, subtracting them and dividing by the number of runs - 1. But how do I combine all these without any subquery?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want any subqueries..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorin, to be fair, you already have the answer - `(max-min)/(count-1)` is indeed correct without going into the specifics of how far apart the runs are.

```
select runner, datediff(max(ran),min(ran)) / (count(ran)-1)
from running
group by runner;
```

Note: MySQL will turn `X / 0` (for where there is only one record for a runner) into NULL because it is indivisable by 0.

Comment: I stand corrected. It appears to be correct and probably the fastest solution.