# Sql: average of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to write a query to calculate the average number days between the shopping for each customer (without using subqueries).

```
create table data {
    customer varchar(20) not null,
    bought date          not null,
    primary key (customer,bought)
}
```

For example,

```
insert into data (customer,bought)
values 
(‘John Smith’,   date ‘2011-02-01’),
(‘Alice Cooper’, date ‘2011-02-01’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-01’),
(‘John Smith’,   date ‘2011-02-02’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-02’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-03’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-04’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-05’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-06’),
(‘Bob Baker’,    date ‘2011-02-07’),
(‘John Smith’,   date ‘2011-02-07’),
(‘Alice Cooper’, date ‘2011-02-08’);
```

should return that John Smith waited 1 day then 5 days, so his average is 3 days. Alice Cooper(!) waited 7 days so her
average is 7. Bob Baker is a daily runner so his average is 1.

I have done something like this:

```
select distinct customer, avg (bought) as average from data;
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This must be homework, because I've seen this exact question (and day gaps) a few days ago - is it? We normally ask for academic honesty and disclosure if it is

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Finding the average number of days between runs for each runners.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237141/sql-finding-the-average-number-of-days-between-runs-for-each-runners)

Comment: It is, yeah. 
I looked it up but hadn't found anything. Thanks!

Comment: Is it it *mean* to ask *median* users what *mode* of average they might mean?

Comment: Note: max(val) - min(val) / (count - 1) is not the arithmetic mean which is the 'average' people in grade school. It will give you quite different answers depending on the data than what the avg function will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL version of the linked answer

```
select customer, (max(bought) - min(bought)) / (count(bought)-1)
from data
group by customer;
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to convert your timestamp in epoch seconds to use avg aggregate function :

```
SELECT
    customer,
    timestamp without time zone '1970-01-01' + cast(
       avg(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM bought::timestamp)
    )::text as interval) 
FROM data
GROUP BY customer;
```

Comment: I need to find AVG on a timestamp without timezone field and then I'm grouping by other field and sorting by this field, with this also work for me? As it displays something like "397559:45:49.20757" not sure how it sorts this

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in similar situation:

```
SELECT customer, avg(AGE(now(),bought)) as waited
FROM data 
GROUP BY customer
```

Answer (score 2):

selecting max-min/count is NOT the average. try:

```
 timestamp 'epoch' + avg(date_part(epoch, date_column))  * interval '1 second'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a group by statement

```
select 
   customer, 
   datediff(D, min(bought), max(bought)) / count(bought) as average
from data
group by customer
```

Whenever you have an *aggregate function* in the *select list*, you have to use grouping on the other fields that are not members of the aggregation.

This was tested on SQL Server and the syntax may differ to Postgresql, which I am not using.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but I get this error on avg "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."??

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT customer, AVG(bought) AS average FROM data GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: I get this error on avg "No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."